# CSVをPandasで扱う際のスペース区切りの問題

Tags: python, pandas

初心者です．
csvファイルをインポートしたいと考えています．
データセットは以下の通りです（簡略化しています）．

```
0   0   0   0   
0  12  12  12
0 123 123 123
```

```
data=pd.read_csv( '○○.csv',sep=' ')
```

上記のようにインポートすると

```
0 NaN NaN NaN   0 NaN NaN NaN   0 NaN NaN NaN  0
0 NaN NaN  12 NaN NaN  12 NaN NaN  12
0 NaN 123 NaN 123 NaN 123
```

となり，スペースの数にNaNのが反映されてしまいます．
何か良い方法はございませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 4):

[pandas の I/O API のドキュメント](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html)によると、

```
read_csv(filename, sep='\s+')
```

とするか、

```
read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=True)
```

とすると良いです。

また、以下のオプションも有用です。

- `header=None`： ヘッダー行を付けない。
- `skipinitialspace=True`： 先頭の空白文字を無視する。

以下実行例です。分かりやすさのため、ファイルから読み込む代わりに文字列からバッファーを作っています。

```
>>> import StringIO
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> buffer = StringIO.StringIO("""0   0   0   0   
... 0  12  12  12
... 0 123 123 123
... """)
>>> data = pd.read_csv(buffer, header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
>>> data
   0    1    2    3
0  0    0    0    0
1  0   12   12   12
2  0  123  123  123
```

#### 参考URL

- [`read_csv` の API Reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) (私が見た時点では pandas 0.20.2 の API Reference です)

  - 概略を把握するには、 [pandas I/O API のドキュメント](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html) の方が分かりやすいです。
- [How to make separator in read_csv more flexible wrt whitespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15026698/5989200) -- 本家 Stack Overflow